# Sorting Subarrays in C Sorts Entire Array Instead?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, sorting

So in this little game I wrote I have a deck of `n_C` cards, each with a unique integer value. 
There are `n_P` players each holding `n_H` cards in their hand.

The deck and the hands share an array, like so:
Player `i_P`'s hand contains all cards from from `deck[i_P * n_H` to `deck[i_P * (n_H + 1) - 1]`. All players combined always hold less than `n_C` cards.

Now I want to sort each player's hand, but not the entire deck (obviously, as this would move some cards between players' hands). I've gone about this like so:

```
void sort_hands(char * deck, size_t n_P) {
    for (size_t i_P = 0; i_P < n_P; i_P++)
        sort_cards(deck + i_P * n_H, n_H);
}
```

And then, using insertion sort (this function will sort an entire array just fine):

```
void sort_cards(char * cards, size_t n) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (size_t j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
            if (cards[j] > cards[j + 1])
                card_swap(cards, j, j + 1);
            else
                break;
    }
}
```

*Note: `card_swap`does  exactly what you would expect it to, it's only 3 statements.

Both `n_C`and `n_H` are `#define`'d constants, `n_P` is a local variable.
When I run the above code with a shuffled deck, and params `n_C = 104, n_H = 10, n_P = 3`, I get:

0: `74 31 53 46 42 75 72 77 70 49`

1: `76 86 99 78 11 94 61 14 41 87`

2: `40 26 92 5 9 3 66 63 101 98`

before subarray sorting and something like:

0: `3 5 9 11 31 42 46 49 53 74`

1: `61 70 75 72 76 77 78 86 94 99`

2: `14 26 40 41 63 66 87 92 98 101`

afterwards. As we can see, some cards have moved hands when they shouldn't have. But the deck has not been sorted across all hands (see e.g. `14` in player 2's hand. How can this be? The way I see it, my coding skills are not at fault, but the compiler seems to be messing with me.

I have observed this behaviour both with the VS15 C++ compiler as well as GCC.

Comment: "in *C*" - then why you tag it as `C++`?

Comment: In `for (size_t j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--)` what happens when `i == 0`, the first iteration of the outer loop? The type `size_t` is unsigned.This looks like a badly implemented bubble sort.

Comment: "my coding skills are not at fault, but the compiler seems to be messing with me." Always doubt that.

Comment: *The way I see it, my coding skills are not at fault,* -- So you're saying that compilers used by thousands of persons and companies all over the world somehow can't execute your simple code correctly?

Comment: If you were to print out the value of `j` in the `sort_cards` loop, don't be shocked by the value you see.  I did, and [this is what I got](https://www.ideone.com/B4Y1WZ)

Comment: At this stage in your C programming career, assume that if the compiler deigns to warn you of a problem, it means you have a serious bug.  The compiler isn't wrong.  Maybe in 30 years time you'll be able to afford to think differently, but I know I have to assume that I'm at fault when the compiler complains, and it is incredibly rare for that assumption to be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I compiled your `sort_cards()` function (after providing the missing `}`),  with GCC 7.2.0 on a Mac and the command line:

```
gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes \
    -Wstrict-prototypes -c cards53.c
```

With these options (the critical one is `-Wextra`), it warns immediately:

```
cards53.c:31:34: error: comparison of unsigned expression >= 0 is always true [-Werror=type-limits]
         for (size_t j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--)
```

That indicates a serious problem.  Especially as on the first iteration of the outer loop, `i` is `0`, so `i - 1` is a very big number.  Frankly, your claim that the function will sort an entire array successfully is bogus.  It won't.  And I don't run code that won't compile with the command line shown.

If you fix that function, your code is then OK.  I used:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define n_H 10
#define n_C 104

static inline void card_swap(char *deck, int i1, int i2)
{
    char t = deck[i1];
    deck[i1] = deck[i2];
    deck[i2] = t;
}

static void sort_cards(char *cards, size_t n)
{
    for (size_t i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = i; j-- > 0; )
        {
            if (cards[j] > cards[j + 1])
                card_swap(cards, j, j + 1);
            else
                break;
        }
    }
}

static void sort_hands(char *deck, size_t n_P)
{
    for (size_t i_P = 0; i_P < n_P; i_P++)
        sort_cards(deck + i_P * n_H, n_H);
}

static void dump_hands(const char *tag, const char *deck, size_t n_P)
{
    printf("%s:\n", tag);
    for (size_t p = 0; p < n_P; p++)
    {
        printf("Player %zu:", p + 1);
        const char *hand = deck + p * n_H;
        for (int i = 0; i < n_H; i++)
            printf(" %3d", hand[i]);
        putchar('\n');
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char deck[n_C] =
    {
        74,  31,  53,  46,  42,  75,  72,  77,  70,  49,
        76,  86,  99,  78,  11,  94,  61,  14,  41,  87,
        40,  26,  92,   5,   9,   3,  66,  63, 101,  98,
    };
    int n_P = 3;
    dump_hands("Before", deck, n_P);
    sort_hands(deck, n_P);
    dump_hands("After", deck, n_P);
    return 0;
}
```

The array is initialized with the sample data you gave; the residue is all zeros, but that doesn't matter for this exercise.

Sample output:

```
Before:
Player 1:  74  31  53  46  42  75  72  77  70  49
Player 2:  76  86  99  78  11  94  61  14  41  87
Player 3:  40  26  92   5   9   3  66  63 101  98
After:
Player 1:  31  42  46  49  53  70  72  74  75  77
Player 2:  11  14  41  61  76  78  86  87  94  99
Player 3:   3   5   9  26  40  63  66  92  98 101
```

Inspection shows that the each sub-array is correctly sorted.

Comment: The way I see it now, my coding skills blow and I can't even debug right. Thanks for the help!

Comment: It helps if you get the compiler to point out your mistakes.  That’s why I showed you the compilation options I use; they keep me out of a lot of trouble.